# Best practice of caching external xmlfeeds

Tags: php, xml, caching, external

I have several (24) external xmlfeeds showing products on my frontpage. See this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199315/get-xml-element-based-on-attribute-value-with-php-from-multiple-xmlfeeds)  for the details of the feeds. Each feed shows one product, but it takes ages to load those feeds each time someone visits my site. The feeds are updated once a day.

What is the best way of caching these feeds? Should i do something with mysql or save xml files locally. I'm not sure where to start. I tried [JG_Cache](http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/02/18/simple-file-based-php-cache-class/), but without luck.

**This is the loop i use:**

```
<?php
    // get xml file contents
    $xmlurl = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'plus_xmlfeed', true );
    if ( !empty( $xmlurl ) ){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);
    }
    $xml->product->name = substr($xml->product->name, 0, 30).'...';
    $desc = substr($xml->product->name, 0, 50).'';
?>

    <li class="span3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="<?php echo $xml->product->productURL ;?>">
          <center><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logos/<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID( ), 'plus_logos', true); ?>.gif"/></center>
          <center><img class="mainimg" alt="" src="<?php echo $xml->product->imageURL ;?>"/></center>
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h5><a href="<?php echo $xml->product->productURL ;?>"><?php echo $xml->product->name; ?></a></h5>
          <div class="maindesc half clearfix"><div class="prijs">&euro; <?php echo $xml->product->price ;?></div><strike style="color: rgb(248, 148, 6);">
            <?php
            foreach ($xml->product->additional->field as $field) {
                               switch((string) $field['name']) {
                                   case 'price_advice':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'fromPrice':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'oldPrice':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'from_price':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'adviesprijs':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'advice_price':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'Fromprice':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                   case 'recommendedPrice':
                                      echo '&euro; ' .$field. '';
                                      break;
                                    }
                                }
            ?>
            </strike>
          <p style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"><?php echo $desc; ?></p></div>
          <div class="btn-group bot"><div class="pull-right"> </div><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $xml->product->productURL ;?>">Kopen</a> <a class="btn" href="#<?php echo 'modal_'.get_the_ID();?>">Info</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
<?php /*end loop*/ ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, consider the following pseudo code:

1. Check for existence of local file with xml contents. Something like /home/db/tempfiles/feed_name_current_date.xml
2. If no matching local local file can be found using the construct from step 1, then load the xml as your doing now
3. After xml has been loaded from URL, save contents using a namespace construct with **feed_name** and **current_date**, so when a new request is made, step 1 will return the local file

I'm curious though, if it's an xml feed, do you not want to store the data in your local system? How do you track purchases etc?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike, I'm just starting to learn xml and how to use it. What is wanted to do was reimport the xml feed once per hour and cache it. Honestly, i havent thought about how to track purchases yet. So i'm not sure how to work with it yet, can you put me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, there are any number of options. Personally, I would write a parser to step through the xml feed, and populate my products database. That way when someone makes a purchase, you can create an order number with the product id which is now local to your dataset. Otherwise it will be difficult to track products as they are probably transitory, through just caching the feeds. What I mean by this is, once a product enters your system, you want to keep it forever, so if you query old orders and want to see the products the data will be available. Otherwise you will end up with orphan ids.

Comment: Yeah sorry for my late reaction. I got it working. I use a parser to populate my database. Using cronjobs to reimport the feeds once per hour (all feeds are updated every 24 hour on different times). My old feed items in the database are only updated if there is new feedinfo. Images i save locally and are also updated after a succesfull cronjob. So thanks for you advise Mike.